# Should element order be determined by HTML or CSS?

Tags: html, css

## What I have:

I have a primary content area followed by two asides:

```
<style>
#primary,#secondary,#tertiary{float:left; width:33%;}
</style>

<div id="content" class="site-content">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">Primary</div>
    <aside id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">Secondary</aside>    
    <aside id="tertiary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">Tertiary</aside>  
</div>
```

## What I need:

I want an `<aside>` to each side of the primary content area. E.g. Two sidebars, one to the left and one to the right.

## What I've tried:

Simply modifying my HTML code by placing `#secondary` before `#primary` feels semantically incorrect:

```
<style>
#primary,#secondary,#tertiary{float:left; width:33%;}
</style>

<div id="content" class="site-content">
    <aside id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">Secondary</aside>    
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">Primary</div>
    <aside id="tertiary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">Tertiary</aside>  
</div>
```

I have attempted using CSS floats but I can't produce the required order `#secondary`, `#primary` and `#tertiary`.

## My question:

Should I modify the order of my elements using HTML or CSS and if CSS, how might I reorder?

https://jsfiddle.net/zLpr8v16/

Comment: @AllDani I speak English fluently. If spelling or grammatical errors exist, I'm quite happy to correct them. What's ambiguous to you?

Comment: What the question is. if it's opinion based it's likely to get closed.

Comment: Don't use float. Use flexbox ordering.

Comment: Basically, do want to know how to do it in CSS, or do you want to know whether to change the HTML or CSS? Because for the second option all I can give is my _opinion_.

Comment: Which ever is best for you. I personally prefer markup, so I easily can see which is intend to be where

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/wnxq44c0/

Comment: @ManojKumar This is perfect, especially considering it leaves my HTML elements in the order I'd like them to appear should CSS be disabled. Please post your comment as an answer to allow me to select it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do with "flex" and "order". check this fiddle; https://jsfiddle.net/zLpr8v16/2/

```
#content{display:flex;}
#primary{order:2; flex:1 0 0;}
#secondary{order:1; flex:1 0 0;}
#tertiary{order:3; flex:1 0 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would really just be up to your preferences. I feel the CSS route is a little more elegant on the other hand. You could achieve this by using `relative` positioning and adjusting the `left` and `right` positions accordingly

Take a look: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zLpr8v16/1/). Of course you can adjust the widths and whatever else as needed.

Comment: Even better is Manoj's comment above so you don't have to worry as much about responsiveness. :)

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation :) Nice to have multiple methods. Please include my comment along with your answer.